# Simple Groups and Conjugacy Classes

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Simple groups can be characterised by following property:

*A group $G$ is simple if and only if for any $1\neq x\in G$, the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$ generates the whole group $G$.*

The question I am interested is natural one related to above fact?

**Q.** If $G$ is a group such that for any $x\in G$, the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$ generates a proper subgroup, what can we say about $G$? (nilpotent, solvable, supersolvable, or else?) Is there characterization (or classification) of such groups?

**Example:** Let $G$ be any non-abelian finite $p$-group. Then for $x\in G$, there is a maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$ containing $x$; then the subgroup generated by the conjugacy class of $x$ is contained in $M$, hence it is proper.

Comment: $A_5 \times C_2 \times C_2$ has this property, so you cannot deduce solvability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite done, but time has been scarce lately:

**Proposition:** In a finite group with non-cyclic abelianization, the subgroups generated by each conjugacy class are proper.

*Proof:* Suppose $G$ is a finite group whose abelianization $G/[G,G]$ is not cyclic. Let $x \in G$. Then $G/[G,G] \neq \langle x \rangle [G,G]/[G,G]$, so there is some maximal subgroup $M/[G,G]$ such that $\langle x \rangle [G,G]/[G,G] \leq M/[G,G]$. Since $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, $M/[G,G]$ is normal, and so $M \lhd G$ is normal, and so contains the subgroup generated by all conjugates of $x$. $\square$

**Proposition:** If $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic and $G$ is finite (or has a composition series), then there is a conjugacy class that generates $G$ as a subgroup.

*Proof:* This is a special case of theorem 4.7 of Berrick–Robinson (1993). $G$ itself has finite composition length, so Robinson's result says that $G$ is the subgroup generated by a single conjugacy class if and only if $G/[G,G]$ is. However, $G/[G,G]$ is generated by a single element (=conjugacy class for abelian groups) if and only if it is cyclic. $\square$

**References:**

- Berrick, A. J.; Robinson, Derek J. S.
  “Imperfect groups.”
  J. Pure Appl. Algebra 88 (1993), no. 1-3, 3–22.
  MR[1233309](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1233309)
  DOI:[10.1016/0022-4049(93)90008-H](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(93)90008-H)

---

*Proof:* (Of conjecture, my attempt) Suppose $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic, generated by $x[G,G]$, and set $N$ to be the subgroup generated by the conjugates of $x$. Let $g \in G$. Then $x^g = x[x,g]$ so $[x,g] \in N$. Hence $x \in Z(G/N)$. ...

**Counterexample:** If $G/[G,G] = \langle x \rangle [G,G]/[G,G]$, then $G$ need not be the subgroup generated by the conjugacy class of $x$.

*Proof:* Take $G = \langle x \rangle \times Y$ with $Y$ non-identity perfect. Then the conjugacy class of $x$ is just $x$ itself, a proper subgroup. $\square$

Fix: the only problem is when $x$ is contained in a maximal normal subgroup not containing $[G,G]$, but in that case the quotient is non-abelian simple, and so a joe random element $y$ of that quotient should be such that $G$ is the subgroup generated by the conjugacy class of $xy$.

Comment: Oh and one more todo: for infinite groups, check if quasi-cyclic abelinizations are the only obstruction.

Comment: interesting! Proposition can be applied to finite $p$-groups, and also to the example by Derek Holt. But, sorry, I do not understand the conjecture (please, just restate it).

Comment: Fixed. If G is perfect and contained in GAP's library, then the conjecture is true. I haven't had a chance to fix the conjecture's “proof” to actually be a proof.

Comment: Where this conjecture appeared first? (or who made this conjecture?)

Comment: I made this conjecture.

Comment: An excellent conjecture if I may say so!

Comment: Probably theorem 4.7 of Robinson 1993 is a proof of the conjecture (that is, my conjecture is just a special case of his result, and at conferences he and his younger students have certainly pointed out to me similar results, so I'm not claiming any originality). I'm a little worried about the result in the paper, and so am checking the details carefully.

Comment: Ok, all good. I'm trying to adapt his proof to this easier situation. 4.8 is more or less my "fix", and 4.9 looks similar, so I think it should not be hard.

Comment: The first "proposition" is trivial in an arbitrary group (even without maximal subgroups) since the image of a conjugacy class in the abelianization is a singleton.

Comment: 1) There are are infinite perfect groups in which every conjugacy class generates a finite subgroup. For instance, if $(G_n)$ is a sequence of nontrivial finite perfect groups, $\bigoplus_n G_n$ is such a group. 2) Whether every finitely generated perfect group is generated by a conjugacy class is a well-known open problem. (I don't remember if it's open when the abelianization is assumed to be cyclic.)