# Characterization of simple groups in terms of its conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

Recently I have seen a post whose [link is the following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436536/simple-groups-and-conjugacy-classes#:%7E:text=A%20group%20G%20is%20simple,generates%20the%20whole%20group%20G).

I am not able to prove the first statement, namely, "A group $G$ is simple if and only if for any $1 \neq x \in G$, the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$ generates the whole group $G$."

Can anyone tell me or give me some references where I can find its proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the conjugacy classes of some $x$ generate a strict subgroup $H\subset G$, can you show that $H$ is a normal subgroup?

And conversely, if $H\subset G$ is a normal subgroup, can you show that for any $x\in H$, its conjugates generate a strict subgroup of $G$?